# How do I set up jQuery Cookie on a 50/50 split landing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, session-cookies, jquery-cookie

I've been diving into jQuery & javascript as of late and need help on a certain project. The intention is to have visitors land on one page and there be a 50% chance they will see div content-box. The other 50% will see div content-box-video. Once they view this div, they will have a cookie dropped on them so that when they visit this same page in the future, they will see the same div they first landed on. This will expire after 30 days. I've been using jQuery Cookie for this.

So far, I've set up Math.random to generate the random number and serve up the div with the specified class based on that. I've been dropping the cookie when cookieValue is set but seem to be stuck. Where am I going wrong here?

Thanks!

**EDIT

Now, all is working except that the cookie is set too quickly. It is reading the new 'setting' of the cookie before it realizes if one is already set. Where would I add a delay so that the browser can check if one is betting set first?**

```
var random = Math.random();
var cookieValue = $.cookie("cookie");

if (cookieValue != 1 || 2) {
if (random < 0.5) {
    cookieValue = 1;
} 
if (random >= 0.5) {
    cookieValue = 2;
} 
}

if (cookieValue === 1) {
$('.content-box').show();
$('.content-box-video').hide();
$.cookie("cookie", 1, {expires : 30, path : '/' });
}

if (cookieValue === 2) {
$('.content-box').hide();
$('.content-box-video').show();
$.cookie("cookie", 2, {expires : 30, path : '/' });
}
```

Comment: looks like the problem is that your second line should be "cookieValue"(lower case) not "CookieValue", isn't it?

Comment: @Mr.Birkoff Oops, I actually have it lowercase in my code. I rewrote it here and accidentally capitalized. Thanks for catching though!

Comment: It would be easier to help you if we knew what being stuck mean in this case. What isn't working exactly?

Also: your condition on random will be ignored if random == 0.5

Comment: @SzymonDrosdzol Sorry, I guess I should have explained that more. I am just stuck on trying to figure out if it is checking if the cookie has been set or not once the visitor loads the page. It seemed like when I was testing it was only setting one value regardless of clearing cookies/refreshing the page.

I was also wondering, does Math.random honestly give this a 50/50 split? I know it generates a random number but I'm wondering if that would secure a split since I'm wanting to A/B test.

Comment: if (cookieValue != 1 || 2)

What is this line supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

What is the starting state of those divs? Do you call this code on load of the document?

Comment: Starting state is display: none. Yes, it is on load.

Comment: Ok! I'm at a place now where all I need to do is delay the setting of the cookie since it is reading it at the same time. How/where would I do that?

Comment: What does i mean reading at the same time? At the same time as what? You need to ask more specific questions if you wish to receive help.